# Execute process with "low" priviliges inside shell with inittab

Tags: linux, shell, boot, init

My goal is to modify the /etc/inittab file in order to execute a spesific program with minimal or customable permissions in an interactive shell with job controls enabled and once it will be terminated I'll continue to the login process. After login, a new shell will open and the last one will be closed automatically.

All these subjects are new to me so I'll much appreciate any commands explanations or small brief what each line does and why it works.

Answer (score 0):

Solution I chose (a little different from what I originally looked for):

Edited the /etc/inittab file for using the agetty command (instead of getty) with auto login ("agetty -a [username]") as "guest" user (user of my choice).

Edited The /etc/profile script (run automatically after login) for running my newly created "AutoRun.sh" script which will execute any process I want inside a new bash shell with job control enabled (interactive shell).

Added a password for root user in order to protect against any unauthorized "su root" command.

- I know it's possible to use the -l option for the agetty command in order to run other command than /bin/login therefore able to run any script/command before performing login.